# Django localization with unnamed string arguments

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

I've made a few Badge classes in Django, each containing some sort of description in a string variable:

```
"You get this badge because you've runned %d meters in %d minutes"
"You get this badge because you've killed %d monsters of the type %s"
```

etc. And the classes also have a function `get_description(badge_level_requirements)`, so in the templates it will be called together with a list to assemble the string for a specific user:

```
class RunnerBadge(Badge):
    des=ugettext_lazy("You get this badge because you've runned %d meters in %d minutes")
    def get_description(cls,badge_level_requirements):
        return cls.des%badge_level_requirements
```

And I've stored the requirements lists in the database without any argument names already :( As shown in the examples, different classes have different numbers of values to fill in the string, the values mean different things as well. So I can't really name the arguments.

However, if I want to internationalize these strings, there'll be errors: `'msgid' format string with unnamed arguments cannot be properly localized` And the language file cannot be generated for this matter.

Is there a way to bypass this error?

**Update**

I've come across this method for bypassing the error without changing database.
In database, the level requirements are stored in a text field in the format of dict:

```
#Requirment of Runner's badge
"{'gold':(100,10),'silver':(50,5),'bronze':(25,2)}"
```

And in class definition, mannually add argument names as 'arg_0','arg_1'... to descriptions. The get_description method is changed to pre-process the data before used for filling description strings.

```
class RunnersBadge(Badge):
    requirements=#get the previous dict from database
    description="You get this badge because you've runned %(arg_0)d meters in %(arg_1)d minutes"

    @classmethod
    def get_description(cls,level):
        '''
        This is actually a method of parent class Badge
        level is either 'gold','silver' or 'bronze'
        '''
        dic={}
        try:
            for (num,val) in enumerate(cls.requirements[level]):
                dic['arg_'+str(num)]=val
        except TypeError:
            dic['arg_0']=cls.requirements[level]


        return cls.description%dic
```

This method keeps most of the current structure (logic and database). And the translator just need to take care of the words' placement.

Comment: `runned` is not a word. You should replace it with `ran`.

Comment: Haha, that's one indication why I'm trying to bypass the restriction :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. like in code, **[variable names should be meaningful within their context](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MeaningfulName)**, 'meter_count' and 'minute_count' are explicit, compared to 'arg_0' and 'arg_1' which are meaningless
2. use **[standard translation in python code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#working-with-lazy-translation-objects)**, it is less error prone and is recognized by the amazingly useful makemessages command
3. use **[use named-string interpolation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation)** (e.g., `%(day)s`) instead of positional interpolation (e.g., `%s` or `%d`) whenever you have more than a single parameter, because the order of parameters can change depending on the language. I.e. germanic and latin languages inverse the noun/adjective order, dates are displayed differently depending on the language, etc, etc ...
4. use **[ran instead of runned](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ran#Verb)**, double check the syntactical validity of your english translation strings

This:

```
class RunnersBadge(Badge):
    requirements=#get the previous dict from database
    description="You get this badge because you've runned %(arg_0)d meters in %(arg_1)d minutes"
```

Becomes:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class RunnersBadge(Badge):
    requirements=#get the previous dict from database
    description=_("You get this badge because you've ran %(meter_count)d meters in %(minute_count)d minutes")
```

Comment: Thanks jpic! Yes I'm still in doubt, and because I've stored the values in database in the format of lists, I'm looking for easier solutions other than changing all the records :).

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you will have to change your records or even your model structure. See my updated answer for details.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation! I can understand why this is so strictly limited here. We're actually working quite specifically for one language within a closely collaborated team. Using i18n was to handle django default strings, and thinking why not apply it to other parts as well? :) Now I come across a "technical" method for dealing with this situation. But probably I'll have to change the model if it's really becoming unmanageable.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I updated the answer and shorten it to the point, considering the code you posted in your question update.

Answer (score 1):

To give a different approach to translating strings that include DB data, or for that any user-generated-content, I strongly recommend [Bablic](http://www.bablic.com). They track the strings that are displayed on your site and notify you of new or untranslated text. They can also integrated with cloud based translation providers so that even newly submitted content will be translated almost immediately without need for you tracking or making any updates to the server-side code or configuration.

Maybe this approach will suit you more?